# Cut off all numbers below "n" in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Fairly new to R. What I'm trying to do is make all the numbers in a matrix be say, 5 and below. For example, if the matrix is like so:

```
1 3 2 5 7
3 8 3 6 2
```

I would like to make it into:

```
1 3 2 5 5
3 5 3 5 2
```

I feel like there must be a more efficient way than doing this by hand every time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enforcing element-wise min or max is easy with `pmin` or `pmax`. In this case, you want the minimum when comparing what's in your matrix to 5.

```
pmin(m1, 5)
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#[1,]  1  3  2  5  5
#[2,]  3  5  3  5  2
```

The *p* stands for *parallel*, indicating that the comparison is element-wise. `min()` or `max()` of course give the global min/max, just a single result. `pmin`/`pmax` are generally useful on two vectors of equal length. Here we take advantage of "recycling", the input `5` is automatically extended ("recycled") to have the same length as the input.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you could do

```
mat[mat > 5] <- 5 


#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#[1,]  1  3  2  5  5
#[2,]  3  5  3  5  2
```

---

@Gregor has got the smartest solution but just to give you more options, you could do

```
ifelse(mat > 5, 5, mat)
```

Or as @Sotos mentioned

```
replace(mat, mat > 5, 5)
```